# Deepcopy object without its functions in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, deep-copy

I am writing a simulation tool for a card game in Python. It simulates every possible action, building a tree with all potential plays and resulting situations.

The current state of the game is represented by an Environment object. This object contains many variables (e.g. turn number) as well as other objects (e.g. enemies) and different functions to modify the object (e.g. attack enemy). Every time the tree branches, I have to create a deep copy of the Environment object first. From what I have seen so far, this deep copy process is the bottle neck in my simulation.

I am looking for ways to make this process faster. One way might be deep copying the object but only shallow copying the functions it contains, which are many. The functions will not change, only the variables and the other objects, therefore a reference to the functions is sufficient.

Long story short - is there a way to deep copy such an object in Python 3, while doing only a shallow copy of the functions in this object?

Comment: are you using classes. Then maybe a `clone` method will help, otherwise simply use dictionary object and deepcopy that and let the functions be defined and called independantly (either as procedural code that take an object as parameter or class methods again taking a n object as parameter). Deepcopy dictionaries would be faster but again it depends on depth and complexity

Comment: @NikosM. yes, the Environment object is a single class containing everything I described. Having a specific clone function, which only copies the required parts, sounds like a good solution. I'll try it!